# export CLOb data from oracle database in UTF8 format

Tags: oracle, utf-8, oracle11g

I have CLOB data stored in the oracle DB and when I query it and print it on the web page, all non English characters appears in `??`. They are in the DB in correct format but when exported to any file or printed it on the web, they appear incorrect.

how to solve this. I am using PHP + OCI8 for fetching records.

Answer (score 0):

Set your NLS_LANG environment variable before starting PHP.  How you do this depends on your operating system and what's starting PHP (e.g. CLI or Apache etc).

Check the PHP OCI8 manual or look at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score 0):

use `AL32UTF8` as encoding type when connecting using `OCI_CONNECT`